# PowerShell variable printing all csv columns from file

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I have a csv file:

```
"SamAccountName","UserPrincipalName","Telephonenumber"
"TUser","TUser@domain.com","+15551112222"
```

I loop through the file:

```
$csvfile = Import-Csv $path
foreach ($row in $csvfile) {
    Write-Host $row.SamAccountName, "$row.SamAccountName"
}
```

The first `$row.SamAccountName` prints the sam account name string from the csv file. If I put the same variable in quotes, it prints an array. My output looks like this:

```
TUser @{SamAccountName=TUser; UserPrincipalName=TUser@domain.com; Telephonenumber=+15551112222}.SamAccountName
```

If I do `.GetType()` on `$row.SamAccountName` is says its a `System.String`. So why does putting it in quotes print an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write it like this:

```
"$row.SamAccountName"
```

only `$row` is recognized as part of the variable and since `$row` is an array that's what it outputs. If you want to write the whole thing to a string try looking into `.ToString()` or wrapping your original statement into a variable like this:

```
"$($row.SamAccountName)"
```

that way it will consider everything part of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not printing an array, it's printing a textual interpretation of the object.

If you want to interpolate an object property in a string, you need to use the syntax `"$($object.property)"`. So changing as below will work:

```
$csvfile = Import-Csv $path
foreach ($row in $csvfile) {
    Write-Host $row.SamAccountName, "$($row.SamAccountName)"
}
```

Or use the format string operator:

```
$csvfile = Import-Csv $path
foreach ($row in $csvfile) {
    "{0}" -f $row.SamAccountName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using double quotes around the "$row.SamAccountName" you are telling PowerShell to get print the row IE the array of objects from that row. As we can see from your output:

```
TUser @{SamAccountName=TUser; UserPrincipalName=TUser@domain.com; Telephonenumber=+15551112222}.SamAccountName
```

This is your Write-Host Statement. First, you are writing  $row.SamAccountName and second you are adding the whole Row object ie the Array. The .SamAccountName in the double quotes is taken as a literal string, therefore, it is not accessing the row to retrieve its value.

If you just put $row in double quotes you will get this:

```
@{SamAccountName=TUser; UserPrincipalName=TUser@domain.com; Telephonenumber=+15551112222}
```

If you want to use double quotes around a variable use this if you are trying to access a sub expression.

```
"$($row.SamAccountName)"
```

This is the subExpression form.

The link below is to help learn about escape characters and string concatenation.
https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html